# HPLIP -> HPAIO Error during device I/O

Tags: openwrt, sane, hplip

I'm running Chaos Calmer 15.05 (openwrt firmware) in a TPLINK WDR3600 and I'm trying to install SANE + HPLIP in order to get scanner over lan network.

I installed sane-libs and sane-daemon + dependencies from official distribuition feed (for Chaos Calmer) and because HPLIP is not available for Chaos Calmer, I had to install [HPLIP for 14.07 in third distribuition url](http://luizluca.github.io/openwrt/14.07/ar71xx/packages/), I don't know if the error below is because of this "version", but.... Well... Using sane-find-scanner I get scanner found out by the system, and scanimage -L returns me:

> device
>   `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP?serial=000000000SS17TR2PR1a'
>   is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP all-in-one

Although scanimage -T returns:

> scanimage: open of device
>   hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP?serial=000000000SS17TR2PR1a
>   failed: Error during device I/O

Can someone help me?

PS: Sane is returning me error:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# saned -d
[saned] main: starting debug mode (level 2)
[saned] saned (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1.0.25 starting up
[saned] do_bindings: [0] bind failed: Address already in use
[saned] do_bindings: [1] bind failed: Address already in use
[saned] do_bindings: couldn't bind an address. Exiting.
[saned] FATAL ERROR; bailing out, waiting for children...
[saned] bail_out: all children exited
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this to work.

I have archer C5 V1 router and the architecture is ar71xx.
I also have HP PSC 2410 multi function printer and scanner.
You will need hplip, sane-daemon and cups.
The software is spread all over the internet.

Step 1: Install hplip and dependencies:

Use them from : http://luizluca.github.io/openwrt/15.05/ar71xx/packages/

```
opkg install <luizluca url>/hplip-sane_3.15.7-1_ar71xx.ipk
opkg install <luizluca url>/hplip-common_3.15.7-1_ar71xx.ipk
opkg install sane-frontends usbutils
```

Make sure scanner is found:

scanimage -L

Now install sane daemon:

```
opkg install sane-daemon
opkg install xinetd
```

edit /etc/xinetd.d/sane-port  -- disable=no

```
/etc/init.d/xinetd enable
/etc/init.d/xinetd start
```

Make sure sane daemon is listening on port 6566:

netstat -an | grep 6566

Now install cups, as hplip is dependent on cups:

Use them from: http://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/oldpackages/

```
opkg install <barrier_breaker url above>/libcups_1.5.4-1_ar71xx.ipk
opkg install <barrier_breaker url above>/libcupsmime_1.5.4-1_ar71xx.ipk
opkg install <barrier_breaker url above>/libcupscgi_1.5.4-1_ar71xx.ipk
opkg install <barrier_breaker url above>/libcupsppdc_1.5.4-1_ar71xx.ipk
opkg install <barrier_breaker url above>/cups_1.5.4-1_ar71xx.ipk
```

I tried to start cups daemon but gave me error on libjpeg.so.62, I had to create a sym link:

ln -s  /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62

Now start cups daemon:

```
/etc/init.d/cupsd enable
/etc/init.d/cupsd start
```

I then installed sanetwain driver on my windows machine and was able to scan using scanimage.

here are the packages installed:

```
root@OpenWrt:/usr/lib# opkg list-installed | grep 'sane\|hplip\|usb'
hplip-common - 3.15.7-1
hplip-sane - 3.15.7-1
kmod-ledtrig-usbdev - 3.18.23-1
kmod-usb-core - 3.18.23-1
kmod-usb-printer - 3.18.23-1
kmod-usb-uhci - 3.18.23-1
kmod-usb2 - 3.18.23-1
libsane - 1.0.25-1
libusb-1.0 - 1.0.19-1
libusb-compat - 0.1.4-1
sane-daemon - 1.0.25-1
sane-frontends - 1.0.25-1
usbutils - 007-1
```

I am also using p910nd print server listening on port 9100.

**With Lede project, this changes a bit (Lede version 17.01.2):**

Use new URL luizluca.github.io/lede/packages-17.01/mips_24kc (need to add http in front)

opkg install (newluizluca url)/hplip-common_3.17.6-1_mips_24kc.ipk

opkg install (newluizluca url)/hplip-sane_3.17.6-1_mips_24kc.ipk

No needs to install CUPS packages.